# Grails Scaffolding & Spring Security Core - Entity 'hellip' not defined

Tags: grails, spring-security

I was testing out Spring Security Core Plugin in Grails and had some problems with the view generated by scaffolding.

I have a simple domain class - Person:

```
package test

class Person {

    static constraints = {
    }

    String  name
    Date    dob

}
```

With this, I used the grails generate-all command to generate the controller and the view. Everything is perfect at this point, and the view works perfectly.

Then I proceeded to secure my app with Spring Security Core. I added the following line to my build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3'
```

And ran the following s2-quickstart command to secure my app

```
grails s2-quickstart test User Role
```

Then I created the login user with ROLE_ADMIN right, and add the following tag at my controller:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    respond Person.list(params), model:[personCount: Person.count()]
}
```

The index page that was working before the Spring Security Core plugin is now giving me this error:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 9 at column 82: Entity 'hellip' not defined
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

I found that the offending line is in my index.gsp:

```
<a href="#list-person" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
```

Does anyone else has this problem? How do I resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Soon

Comment: I was using grails version 3.0.4 before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been resolved after I upgraded to grails version 3.3.0 and spring security core 3.2.0.M1.

Thanks.